# In Elm, how can i open a websocket based on user input?

Tags: websocket, elm

I have a broker that accepts websocket connections, and routes messages to that connection based on url query parameters.

I thought about writing a client (in Elm) that accepts input from the user, then opens a websocket connection based on that input. How would i do this using the (high level) Websocket module (if possible)?

Comment: Have you checked the  [Elm WebSocket module](https://guide.elm-lang.org/architecture/effects/web_sockets.html)?

Comment: Yes, but i didn't realize that subscriptions are dynamic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can easily be achieved using the Websocket module. Since subscriptions are updated when the model is updated, it is just a matter of yielding a list of subscriptions created by Websocket.listen. If a user action adds a value to the model, that value can be used to create a new subscription.

```
type alias Model = 
  { servers: List Url }

subscriptions model = 
  Sub.batch (List.map (\url -> Websocket.listen url ...) model.servers)
```